# Ajax response in datatables

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, json, datatables

I was implementing an interface with uses `DataTables` and excel files. Motive is upload an excel and then show it in `DataTables`. 
As I didn't find any javascript library which parse the excel and provide it to `DataTables`. The only option is ot send the data to the front end struts/ java and send back the json. 
Is it possible to have `DataTables` waiting for the json by Ajax without sending the request. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think, it is possible in html5 and javascript. run and test the code below.

```
<html>
</head>
<script>
  function readBlob() {

    var files = document.getElementById('files').files;

    if (!files.length) {
      alert('Please select a file!');
      return;
    }

    var file = files[0];
    var start = 0;
    var stop = file.size;

    var reader = new FileReader();

    // If we use onloadend, we need to check the readyState.
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
      if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
        document.getElementById('byte_content').textContent = evt.target.result;
      }
    };

    var blob = file.slice(start, stop);
    reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
  }

</script> 
</head>

<body>
<input type="file" id="files" name="file" accept=".csv"  />
<span class="readBytesButtons">
  <button onclick="readBlob()">entire file</button>
</span>
<div id="byte_range"></div>
<div id="byte_content"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

we can extract the excel data as text by FileReader in javascript.
if you want to display the data in datatable, please apply your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, but no Ajax is need in your case. How would i do it? See below:

Have a form to upload the excel file to my struts implementation. Then do the processing of the excel file and return the contents in pure html/table format. Then do a simple datatables initialization on page load and your are finished!

**UPDATE**

For pagination, datatables support ajax like this:

```
var oTable = "";
$(document).ready(function() {
  oTable = $('#htmltableID').dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "/myAjaxSource.jsp?page="+pageNumber+",
    "sServerMethod": "POST",
    "iDisplayLength": 50
  });
}
```

Then in your myAjaxSource.jsp you get the parameter `page` sent by the ajax URL and return the appropriate data (json)

Comment: Pagination over server will be the issuse in this case. As the excel can be big. Is there no option in AJax to wait for the data and or an javascript funtion triggerred by in comming GET request.Example can be like gmail were mails are pushed to frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Yes off course,

I think you want to try something like this

1. upload file to server

   - read the excel file in strut action, save it on disk in temp folder and return file name to your JSP.
2. when first step done then make Ajax Call to struts action

   - pass file name as parameter fom datatable ajax call
   - load file from disk read it and populate in Pojo or VO object
   - create Json from  Pojo using gosn or jakson api
   - finally return json.

further see  [data table ajax source](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/ajax.html)